# twitter oauth must authorize user everytime they login

Tags: twitter

I am adding twitter oauth login to my site . and so far i got it to work using oauth.
however every time i login i go through the whole authorization process. ( the prompt that allows the user to request or deny the application)
is there a way to by pass that once the user has authorized the app?
Perhaps i am misunderstanding the process also if so could you please clarify?
thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

must use oauth_authenticate_url instead of oauth_authorize_url

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As shortcut, the URL is https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, after I solved it I made a template to set it all up. http://blog.ruedaminute.com/2010/12/everything-you-need-to-access-twitter-using-tweetr-api-and-air/